# Inheriting resources from android libraries

Tags: android, resources

I have a question about inheriting resources from android libraries.

Assume you have an android library project and in that library you put some resources (let's say strings for the moment) under the package name com.libexample

Now in an android project under the package name com.example, I reference the library I created earlier.

If I want to use one of the strings of the library I can get it by using

```
getString(com.libexample.R.string.test_string);
```

My question is, is it possible for a string resource in my main project to get assigned the same integer ID as a string in my library? Cause if it is, then the above code statement would in fact be equal to :

```
getString(R.string.new_string);
```

assuming that the new_string recourse was assigned the same ID as the test_string resource.

Comment: I assume that it would be possible for the ids to match, unless one of two possibilities holds true:  1.  The Android compiler is smart enough to search every library for every class named `R` and check each one for ids that are already used (very unlikely, I think).  2.  The ids in `R` are not entirely random and incorporate enough information from their compilation unit that ids in `com.libexample.R` are effectively guaranteed not to coincide with ids in `com.someotherthing.R` (more likely).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the compiler adds the resources under the same generated R.java file automatically which prevents any conflicts.